# What is the benefit of having a String class for Rcpp

Tags: c++, rcpp

I was wondering what is the benefit for having an Rcpp String class (documented [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/classRcpp_1_1String.html)).

It is possible to convert between `Rcpp:String` and `std::string`, but why not just use `std::string` since many of its methods are already well implemented. I'm guessing there must be a reason for doing this. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy: There is a `STRSXP` and Rcpp types are first and foremost *proxy objects* for the underlying R types. So no copies.

Using `std::string` would entail copies on the way in and out.  You don't want that.

Comment: Alright, that was easy thanks. Quick question for you, what is your favorite way to convert an `Rcpp::String` to `std::string`. Is there a method for it? is it `get_cstring`?

Comment: `std::string easyToo = Rcpp::as<std::string>(someThingElse)`.  Or if you want `std::string`, don't instantiate a `Rcpp::string` in the first place -- Rcpp Attributes does all this for you.